# SonarQube waiting satuts check

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

Try to prevent the merge of pull requests with a failed Quality Gate by adding a "SonarQube/quality gate"
In PR request i can see

[image]

in branch policy added
[image]

I can see the result in extenstion

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you check github branch rules?

1. Settings -> Branches -> Edit Related Rule(eg. master)
2. Require status checks to pass before merging

Verify `SonarQube Code Analysis` is checked

Comment: issue is its showing 'waiting' even though its passed